# Microsoft Dynamics Online - Create View Url

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online has a button called "Email a link" or "Send a link".
This creates the link and then sets up a mail with mailto:

Internet Browsers block the script, when the default for mailto: is a browser. So without an e-mail application, you can't easily copy the url to send it to someone.

My question is, is it possible (with ribbon workbench) to make a button so that, instead of a mail, the link is available in something like a pop up dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the W3C Clipboard API. Make your button invoke a custom Javascript function copying the form url to the clipboard. The Clipboard API is supported by all major browsers. See [W3C Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) and [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).

You can create a form url using the following (generic) function:

```
function createFormUrl() {
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()
        + "/main.aspx?pagetype=entityrecord&etn="
        + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

    if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() === 1) {
        return url;
    }

    return (url + "&id=" + encodeURIComponent(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the URL when accessing the CRM doesn't change, so it's not possible to just copy the URL. However after looking around, people talk about refreshing the page, and looking at the HTTP request being sent to get the URL. Is this possible with a javascript function?

Comment: @Abintu: indeed the window location is of no use here. Instead we can use the CRM Javascript API. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-handle-mailto-behavior-in-ie-chrome-opera-firefox-safari-on-windows-7

You may find the appropriate way to configure your browser to unblock mailto scripts.